# IPython notebook doubles up the qqplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels

I just tested the statsmodels.api.qqplot function in an IPython notebook (Jupyter) running Python 3.6, and got two identical plots in a column (I only asked for one). What is going on?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
test = np.random.normal(0,1, 1000)
sm.qqplot(test, line='45')
```

Comment: see https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1265 or https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3474

Comment: Thanks for that! I followed the 1st link's advice and fixed it with this:
`_ = sm.qqplot(e, line='s')`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add ";" is the simplest hack.

For example:

```
sm.qqplot(test, line='45');
```

I got the answer from
@lightalchemist from github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1265.